# Trying to execute a program in VS Code, but i keep getting an error

Tags: .net-4.0, runtime-error, .net-4.8

[Running] dotnet run --project "c:\Users\Bloxxel64\CodeProjects\AssetStudio\AssetStudioGUI\AssetStudioGUI.csproj"
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.403\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1217,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.0 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks

The build failed. Fix the build errors and run again.

[Done] exited with code=1 in 3.872 seconds

I've Already installed the latest .NET Framework and SDK but i can't get it to run.
I cannot figure out how to fix this. any advice?

Answer (score 0):

There are helpful links in the microsoft forum [Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/28eefd9c-9e2b-4ada-8da9-c020de6cd531/error-msb3644-the-reference-assemblies-for-framework-quotnetframeworkversionv461quot-were?forum=visualstudiogeneral) and StackOverflow [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383255/error-msb3644-the-reference-assemblies-for-framework-netframework-version-v4) that have the question on your type Target frameworks are differents.