# Maui app on Mac-Catalyst throwing .net framework reference assembly error

Tags: .net, maui, mac-catalyst

I am building a Maui app and we are trying to build & publish locally on a Macbook Pro for testing MacCatalyst but are receiving the error  `/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.408/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1220,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application.` which obviously was not available on MacOS, however none of the project files contain a target of V4.0 it is all set to 6.0 so I cannot figure out why he is receiving this error on Mac specifically.

Comment: Perhaps it is an issue with one of the nuget packages being used.

Comment: I agree with @ToolmakerSteve, it does sound like a problem with a nuget package. .NET Framework shouldn't be a dependency in a MAUI app. Check your packages and make sure they don't have any dependencies on .NET Framework. Only .NET Standard and .NET 6.0 or higher are compatible with MAUI. Maybe post your *.csproj* file. Does this happen with a blank project, too?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to uninstall the VS and re-launch the setup and Modify --> Individual Components: .NET Framework 4.7.2 targeting pack.

For more info you can refer to this case: [error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" were not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383255/error-msb3644-the-reference-assemblies-for-framework-netframework-version-v4).